# extra 5px padding on both left and right side of the column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple html/bootstrap 3.3 code which looks like

```
<div class="container" >
 <div class="row body">
  <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>

 <div class="row nav">
  <div class="col-xs-12">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

The second row's col-xs-12 is smaller than the above row. I have extra 5px padding on both left and reight.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: you might have some other css property, which is override default one. because above code is looks okay

Comment: We don't know what the class " body" is doing.